# Best solution for Monitor with one USB-C Port on multi Client

Tags: display, kvm-switch, usb-c

I have a Monitor with one USB-C port and 4 USB-A Ports (Hub).
I've connected my mouse and keyboard to the monitor with USB-A and my Windows Laptop and my wife's MacBook with USB-C. I have Video signal and keyboard and mouse inputs. So this works as expected.

Now I also have an Desktop PC with no USB-C port. So I've connected to the monitor with HDMI. To get the mouse and keyboard working, I've connected PC USB-A to Monitor USB-A. This does not work. I think my Monitor does not support it. Note: I only need to connect Mouse and Keyboard no other accessories.

So there a a few ways to get it to work.

- USB-C KVM switch (although video signal is not needed)
- Two Logitech Bolt receiver one plugged in on Monitor and PC (have to switch it on mouse and keyboard)

Or are there any better alternatives? What are the pro and cons?

[Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2yJm.png)